# How can I rename this Android Project with hardcoded libraries

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Currently I am using Android studio to make my first app. I am using a library that I believe requires the app to be called "com.camera.simplemjpeg" and if I try to refactor the name the app just crashes when trying to utilize the library. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

**In Android Studio, you can do this:**

For example, if you want to change `com.example.app` to `my.awesome.game`, then:

1. In your ***Project pane***, click on the little gear icon ( [image: Gears icon] )
2. Uncheck / De-select the `Compact Empty Middle Packages` option

[image: Compact Empty Middle Packages]

3. Your package directory will now be broken up in individual directories
4. Individually select each directory you want to rename, and:

   - Right-click it
   - Select `Refactor`
   - Click on `Rename`
   - In the Pop-up dialog, click on `Rename Package` instead of Rename Directory
   - Enter the new name and hit **Refactor**
   - Allow a minute to let Android Studio update all changes
   - *Note: When renaming `com` in Android Studio, it might give a warning. In such case, select* **Rename All**

[image]

5. Now open your ***Gradle Build File*** (`build.gradle` - Usually `app` or `mobile`). Update the `applicationId` to your new Package Name and Sync Gradle, if it hasn't already been updated automatically:

[image: Refactor Directories]

6. ***Done!*** Anyways, Android Studio needs to make this process a little simpler.

Comment: I haven't tried this exact set of steps but if a normal refactor wont work I don't think this will work either.

Comment: Just tried and it made absolutely no difference. Still crashed when trying to access the library.

Comment: try clean and rebuild project

Comment: Still nothing. I'm sure it has to do with the library.

Comment: try something like this
You don't have to touch AndroidManifest.
Instead do the following: 

 1. right click on the root folder of your project.
 2. Click "Open Module Setting". 
 3. Go to the Flavours tab. 
 4. Change the applicationID to whatever package name you want. Press OK.

The decoupling of Package Name and Application ID is explained here:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Comment: This works. But it would be cool to figure out how to properly refactor it with a stubborn library.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In the library that I was using I had to change all the references to the old app name and then recompile it using the NDK.